# How to denote the first or the second part of a Cartesian product?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology, relations

I have a set of the form
$$S:=\{(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2),\ldots,(a_n,b_n)\}.$$

Is there a notation for the first (or second) part of $S$ without defining them?

In fact, I can say let $A:=\{a_1,a_2\ldots,a_n\}$ and $B:=\{b_1,b_2\ldots,b_n\}$  but here I am defining them. Is there a notation like $S(1)$ to denote $A$ or $S(2)$ to denote $B$?

Comment: To be clear, if $S=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$, then by your definition $A=B=\emptyset$.

Comment: These are the images of the "canonical projection" maps, usually denoted $\pi_i$. So the first set in the product I would write as $\pi_1(S)$. But usually the factors of the product are given beforehand for these projection maps to make sense...

Comment: @Nick To my understanding, even when the definition makes sense, $$\pi_1(S)=\{x\,:\,\exists y,\ (x,y)\in S\}\neq\{x\,:\,\forall y,\ (x,y)\in S\}$$

Comment: Oh, my mistake. You're talking about $S$ in general being a subset of the product, not the product itself.

Comment: @Nick I think the OP actually means what you wrote, but it's not up to me to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common terms are *domain* and *range*.

Recall that a relation is a set of ordered pairs. If $S$ is a relation, then $\operatorname{dom}(S)$ is the domain of $S$ which is the set $\{a\mid\text{ There is some }b\text{ such that }(a,b)\in S\}$. Similarly, we define the range of $S$ is $\operatorname{rng}(S)=\{b\mid\text{ There is some }a\text{ such that }(a,b)\in S\}$.

It is always the case that $S\subseteq\operatorname{dom}(S)\times\operatorname{rng}(S)$. But it is not often the case that these two are equal.

(The notation $\operatorname{rng}$ can vary a lot, but the context should always make it clear what is the set.)